# Error with a pygame project very early into it

Tags: python, python-2.7

Basically this is all I have so far and it would appear there is something wrong with my computer or the py.game.

here is my code so far:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((1280,720))
pygame.display.set_caption('Python Platformer')

python_char = pygame.image.load('python_char')
```

when run in the python launcher I get two errors.

> 1. 20:52:53.731 WARNING:  140: This application, or a library it uses, is using the deprecated Carbon Component Manager for hosting Audio Units. Support for this will be removed in a future release. Also, this makes the host incompatible with version 3 audio units. Please transition to the API's in AudioComponent.h.
> 2. line 8, in 
>    python_char = pygame.image.load('python_char')

I left out the directory because I dont see them being of much help but if needed I can always add them in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you entered here only has one issue for me.
Make sure you have the right version of Pygame installed that corresponds with your python version.
For the second error, change ('python_char') with a supported image file. Example:

```
python_char=pygame.image.load('snake.png')
```

but replace snake.png with the name of your image.

Comment: oh haha the image error was really me just not thinking. I was focusing on what was going on with pygame because I knew it had worked for me in the past. Frustrated I came here. Anyways thanks pal, I will be sure to update it. I need to be a little more patient before come to stackflow.